# Android: What is wrong with my custom ImageView inherritance?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I just started with Android and thought it would be easy to create a new class of an image which I will later move around and so on, just playing with Android basically. Well, it seems its not as easy as expected. I get a NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
```

#### xml layout

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".Start">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

#### Main activity

```
package com.andreiv.snake;

import com.andreiv.snake.util.Picture;
import com.andreiv.snake.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Start extends Activity {

    ImageView img;
    Picture pic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        pic = new Picture(img.getContext());
        pic.drawPic();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    }
}
```

#### Picture class

```
package com.andreiv.snake.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.andreiv.snake.R;

/**
 * Created by andrei on 7/2/2014.
 */
public class Picture extends ImageView{

    public Picture(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public Picture(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public Picture(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void drawPic() {
        setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to verify: you do indeed have a resource in your drawables directory called "pic"?

Comment: You should call `setContent` before trying to find view by id

Comment: Marco,sure I have the resource. Else R.drawable.pic would not be usable. MarsAtomic, you are right, my bad, I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - you need to set the content view before trying to use FindViewById.

Second - you don't need to take the context from the image, you can give the activity itself (activity extends context), in your case even this is not necessary, since the view will get the context automatically when the framework will inflate your xml.

Third - if you want that your extended view to be in inflated in the xml, you must put it's class name in the xml (and not the ImageView class)

```
public class Start extends Activity {

    Picture img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    img = (Picture)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.drawPic();

   }
}

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".Start">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

<com.andreiv.snake.util.Picture
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: I tried this the first time got unexpected cast to Picture, I didnt change the xml though. Eveything works fine now...just learned a new thing ^^. Thank you very much